# Site with beatable PLO rake?

Tags: rake

I've just started getting into PLO but have quickly realized the low-stakes games are next to unbeatable because of rake.  Apparently paying 2buyins/1k hands in rake is not uncommon.

An example of a site with a huge rake at the smaller stakes is PokerStars.
Here you can see the players that played the most hands in the last 12 months at the 0.50/1.00$ level, which is a rather soft level with a lot of people that don't really know what they're doing.

Only 3 of these 25 regular players are winners, they altogether paid almost $8 million in rake for the 63 million hands they played.
[image: Pokerstars rake]

[Source](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/153/high-stakes-pl-omaha/no-money-plo-everyone-raked-1315665/)

Does anyone play at a site that treats PLO differently?

Comment: can you provide some examples? Are you talking about certain sites?#

Comment: What specific rake rates are you seeing? It has been a few years since I took a detailed look at micro stakes PLO, but I have recent students who have moved from the $5 buyin games to the $50 buyin games showing a significant net profit at each level. Usually rake is a simple fraction of the pot, and frankly most sites I have seen host *tons* of players who are bad enough to let a good player do significantly better than the rake rates.

Comment: The number of hands and rake paid are not based only on those 25 people; the above screenshot is probably totalling everyone in your DB for those numbers.  If you add the rake paid for the 25 players, it's not equal to the total shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you want is listed [here](http://www.pokertableratings.com/poker-rake-analysis/pot-limit-omaha). According to the table, PokerStars has the lowest rake at PLO games. Not surprising for me, though.

Hope it helps.

Good luck!